# how to loop using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have been working on a count down for most of today, and now I am stuck on looping. Without the for loop everything works fine the count down hits 0 and reloads, but with the for loop it doesn't count down properly and skips numbers. What I would like to accomplished here is to have the timer count down completely and after 3 complete count downs it will stop completely. What am I doing wrong here?

```
var number = 25;
var i;

function countdown() {
    $('#display').html("Redirecting in " + number + " second(s).");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        number--;
        if (number < 0) {
            window.location.reload();
            number = 0;
        }
    }
    setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    countdown();
});
```

Comment: If it works without the loop, why are you still using it?

Comment: You decrement `number` four times in the loop--of course it skips numbers. You also reload, which will start the whole process over again--unless you store the "total" count somewhere persistent, like in a cookie or something, every time you reload your JS starts all over.

Comment: you're decrementing `number` in your `for` loop 4 times. Change it to `for (i = 0; i < 1; ++i) {` and it will work. But what's the point of the loop in that case?

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish here, the for loop doesn't make sense at all and you probably don't need it. If you want to count down 3 times then hold two counters (like `number`, and `round`), decrease `number` every time, and add special handling when `number` reaches 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you want to count down from 25 for 3 times, and then reload the page. Am I right?

```
var number = 25;
var i = 0;

function countdown() {

    $('#display').html("Redirecting in " + number + " second(s).");

    number--;

    if (number == 0) {

        number = 25;
        i++;

    }

    if (i == 3) {

        window.location.reload();

    }

    setTimeout(countdown, 1000);

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    countdown();
});
```

Comment: Count down and reload 3 times if thats possible. if not is it possible to count down and reload an iframe

Comment: There are a few ways of doing it. I think I'd save myself the trouble and set a `session` in PHP. Then let PHP output a small code of JS that would set your `i` value. The session itself would obviously increase each page request. Though manual reloads would also increase the `i` value.